# create and save cookies on onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

Can anyone help me set up a cookie function that can take user input by checking which link the user clicked on and then redirect them to that link and create a cookie for it so the next time the user comes they automatically get redirected.

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong. I want multiple links and clicking on each link should create a cookie and redirect the user.

Can anyone provide a working jsFiddle please.

The code is below please help:

```
  //Html
  <a href="" onClick="redirectOne('/home')">something site</a> 
  <a href="" onClick="redirectTwo('/home')">something2 site</a>
  // Javascript
  function redirectOne(state)
  {
    createCookie('state', state, 90);
    window.location.href = "www.something1.com" + state;
  }

  function redirectTwo(state)
  {
    createCookie('state', state, 90);
    window.location.href = "www.something2.com" + state;
  }

  var cookie = readCookie('state');
  if (cookie != null) 
  {
    window.location.href = "www.something.com" + cookie;
  }

 function createCookie(name,value,days) {
 if (days) 
   {
     var date = new Date();
     date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
     var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
   }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
 }

 function readCookie(name) {
   var nameEQ = name + "=";
   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
   }
     return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
   createCookie(name,"",-1);
 }
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code ? Do you get any error message ?

Comment: The issue is that no matter what link I click on it always saves the "www.somethingOne.com" cookies. Even if I click on the somethingTwo link it still saves the somethingOne cookie and I redirected there.

Comment: Is this the code giving you troubles ? I'm failing to understand how your cookies are used. On top of that, in your snippet, they're always set to the same value with  `redirectOne` and `redirectTwo`

Comment: thank you so much for replying. Appreciate it. Yes the code is giving me trouble. I copied the code from a website. with redirectOne and Two I sending in the same value but within the function the URL are different. Both redirect user to the home page of two different sites. If possible could you create a simple example for me. Apologies but Im really stuck on this. thanks again.

Comment: @fxm The purpose of this code is to give users and option to select their region. When a user comes on the site they are presented with a option to selection regions such as UK, Australia etc. When click on the region they want to go to I want it to create a cookie and every time that user comes they get redirected to the region they selected before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call this line in each function

```
 createCookie('state', state, 90);
```

It's taking the value of '/home' from the onClick event and passing it to the cookie creation routine.  You should be passing in something other than '/home' for both functions.

```
  <a href="" onClick="redirectOne("www.something1.com")">something site</a> 
  <a href="" onClick="redirectOne("www.something2.com")">something2 site</a>
  // Javascript
  function redirectOne(state)
  {
    createCookie('state', state, 90);
    window.location.href = state+'/home';
  }
```

You do not need the redirectTwo function at all.